# Parallelism in spark.mllib

Tags: scala, apache-spark, parallel-processing, apache-spark-mllib

Let's say I have an object `data` of type `Array[RDD]`.
I want to learn **independent** Machine learning models on each `RDD` in this object. For example, with random forests:

```
data.map{ d => RandomForest.trainRegressor(d,2,Map[Int,Int](),2,"auto","gini",2,10) }
```

When I launch this job with `spark-submit --master yarn-client ...`, the independent learning tasks does not seem to be parallelized on multiple nodes. Almost all the job is done by only one node (namely node 10 here), as it can be seen on the screenshot from the application UI:

[image]

*Addendum*

For completeness, the whole code is below:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors
import org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint
import org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.RandomForest


object test {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("test")
    conf.set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

    // Load data
    val rawData = sc.textFile("data/mllib/sample_tree_data.csv")
    val data = rawData.map { line =>
      val parts = line.split(',').map(_.toDouble)
      LabeledPoint(parts(0), Vectors.dense(parts.tail))
    }

    val CV_data = (1 to 100).toArray.map(_ => {val splits = data.randomSplit(Array(0.7, 0.3)) ;  splits(0)})

    CV_data.map(d => RandomForest.trainClassifier(d, 2, Map[Int, Int](), 2, "sqrt", "gini", 2, 100))

    sc.stop()
    System.exit(0)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `RandomForest.trainClassifier` can be seen as an *action*, because it eagerly triggers the execution of some of the involved RDD calculations. Thus, whenever you call `RandomForest.trainClassifier`, Spark jobs will be submitted to the cluster and executed.

Since the `map` operation on Scala `Array` is performed sequentially, you end up executing one `trainClassifier` job after another. In order to execute the jobs in parallel, you have to call `map` on a parallel collection. The following code snippet should do the trick:

```scala
CV_data.par.map(d => RandomForest.trainClassifier(d, 2, Map[Int, Int](), 2, "sqrt", "gini", 2, 100))
```

Comment: Thank you for your very clear answer. But curiously, adding `.par` to CV_data did not change the behavior of the job: all the work is done by one node.

Comment: Maybe you have too few partitions set. Try to increase them when you read the input file via `sc.textFile(..., #partitions)`.